# Integration of OAM Webgate SSO with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication, single-sign-on

I am working to move an ASP.NET MVC site currently using FormsAuthentication to use SSO (Webgate/OAM).

The Webgate is installed and exposed thru an ISAPI filter on IIS and redirects to SSO page.

In FormsAuthentication, we would get HttpContext.Current.User as IPrincipal. But with SSO authentication, IPrincipal in HttpContext.Current.User is no over available.

[This documentation from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12530_01/oam.1014/e10356/aspdotnet.htm#BIIJAHHE) says that protected ASP.Net should expect WindowsPrincipal as its IPrincipal. But replacing HttpContext.Current.User with WindowsPrincipal is not helping either.

Is there a way I can capture the identity of authenticated user inside ASP.NET application?

Comment: A question from a new user (can't comment) - "Can you please share the code you used to get the response sent by oam please?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time revealed that when SSO redirected authenticated user, back to my app, it shared username in HTTP headers. I realize I should have dig thru the SSO response.

Anyways, I was able to capture the identity of the user and set up FormsAuthentication cookie with this identity. This approach left me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003737/setting-up-formsauthentication-after-sso-authentication), if anyone has an interest to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

OAM 11g Now supports OOTB integration with the .Net Applications (MVC). You can refer the http://howtoidm.blogspot.in/2015/03/oam-11g-net-application-integration.html