# OAM 11g apache 2.4 WebGate how to retrieve logged-in user-info

Tags: oracle11g, single-sign-on, apache2.4, oracle-access-manager

[Apache 11g WebGate for OAM 11gR2](http://onlineappsdba.com/index.php/2014/06/17/apache-11g-webgate-for-oam-11gr2/#comment-3140422)  @Mahendra thanks for the article, though its late for the blog's timeline, only recently I had to configure Apache2.4 Webgate on Windows2012 server; all steps went through well & Apache restarted properly.
On inspecting a simple request sent to Apache server as http:///,
I could see `OAM_Authn*Cookie*` elements in the Request header; but, there's no information on the authenticated user-info in the response;

Any pointers to following points will be of great help.

- log the user-info through the Apache request logging at VirtualHost level
- retrieve logged-in user info, within a down-stream Tornado-Web-application that's hosted on Apache using VirtualHost entry

thanks in advance.

PS: I found something closer @ [Webgate SSO for .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003737/setting-up-formsauthentication-after-sso-authentication), but its about `logout` scenario in `C#` context.

Comment: found more info @ [ref](http://www.oraworld.co.uk/step-by-step-flow-of-user-request-for-sso-via-oracle-access-manager/#comment-47259)

Comment: one more [ref article](http://fusionsecurity.blogspot.in/2011/04/oam-11g-single-sign-on-and-oam-11g.html)

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?  I am able to set OAMAuthnCookie but its contents are just a big encoded string.  Any idea how to get the user name out of it?

Comment: from the config info shared by the admin for OAM-WebGate, the logged-in user credential was made available thru http-request-header using key: 'Oam_remote_user'; so it depends on the individual config settings used by respective admin